# screen jumping black out and off continuously instead of just turn off, after auto screen off set in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am setting turning off screen in 5 mins when no active in my windows.

but currently, I found when the timer is up, screen just black out for 5 secs or so, and turn off, but instantly, it back on to black out for 5 secs then off ... this continuous loop.

it won't just turn off the display like it used be.

Im in windows 10, up to date driver of video card and monitor.

anything I can do to fix this? thanks.

Comment: Perhaps also update the Power Management driver (looks after issues like screen turning off), BIOS and Chipset as well

Comment: BIOS has no updating, but I updated the chipset driver which including a branded power management, this sort out my problem. :)  thanks! if you move the comment to answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps also update the Power Management driver (looks after issues like screen turning off), BIOS and Chipset as well.  You noted that the Chipset / power management driver fixed the issue